# How to get last value in a column of pgfplotstable?

Tags: pgfplotstable

I need to get a last value in a column of a pgfplotstable.
I have the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread{
X
1
2
3
}\tbl

\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\tbl}
\pgfmathparse{\pgfmathresult-1}
\pgfplotstablegetelem{\pgfmathresult}{X}\of{\tbl}

The last value of column `X' is \pgfplotsretval.
\end{document}
```

This produces the following output:

[image: .0 The last value of column 'X' is 3.]

In other words, the value is read correctly, but the `\pgfplotstablegetelem` command renders `.0`.
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `int` since otherwise internally pgf will use numbers like `3.0`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread{
X
1
2
3
}\tbl

\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\tbl}
\pgfmathparse{int(\pgfmathresult-1)}
\pgfplotstablegetelem{\pgfmathresult}{X}\of{\tbl}

The last value of column `X' is \pgfplotsretval.
\end{document}
```

[image]

An even simpler possibility is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread{
X
1
2
3
}\tbl

\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\tbl}
\pgfplotstablegetelem{\the\numexpr\pgfplotsretval-1}{X}\of{\tbl}

The last value of column `X' is \pgfplotsretval.
\end{document}
```